# Duplicate Google Spreadsheet on Demand

Tags: java, javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a pretty complex Google spreadsheet.  I would like a user to be able to click a button or follow a link, and get a copy of this spreadsheet where they can fill in data.  I would later check process this data manually.

Is there anyway I can do this via a complicated link, or some Javascript, or possibly even using a server side language (e.g. Python, Java).

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Rather than force a user to create a spreadsheet that you verify, you can email them a form to fill out with [Google forms](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809), and the answers get aggregated back on your spreadsheet.
- Use the docs API to [copy documents](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CopyingDocs).
- Use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/scripts.html) to automate the process (it's essentially javascript).

Comment: I ended up using Google Apps Script to create a copy of the spreadsheet, and then assigned that to a drawing of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the document from the client side:

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CopyingDocs

Using the Java API, it would seem you'd have to export the document and then upload it:

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html